# In what city or town is Kvothe's Inn located?

Tags: the-kingkiller-chronicle

In the [*Kingkiller Chronicles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kingkiller_Chronicle) (*The Name of the Wind* and *Wise Man's Fear*), by [Patrick Rothfuss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Rothfuss), what city or town is Kvothe's inn located?

Comment: It's mostly described as a small village.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kingkiller_Chronicle),

> When Chronicler wakes, he is at the Inn in Newarre, and at once claims to recognize Kote as Kvothe, a hero who had disappeared and is believed dead after accomplishing amazing, and at times terrible, deeds. Chronicler has come to record Kvothe's story, who at first refuses, but eventually agrees, telling the scribe it will take three days (setting up the structure of the trilogy of novels).

It's likely in Newarre.

Comment: Early in Chapter 6 Kvothe says, "You are, in fact, in the middle of Newarre."

Comment: If you listened to the audible book version, it sounds a lot like "in the middle of nowhere", which I think is why the name was chosen.

Answer (score 9):

It was definitely called Newarre. Chapter 4 of *The Name of the Wind* is titled "Halfway to Newarre".  Where the Chronicler sees the lights of Newarre but can't make it all the way, and thus finds his way to Kvothe's campfire.

At the start of chapter 5 Kvothe brings Chronicler back to Newarre,

> It was well past midnight by the time Kote made it back to Newarre [...]

after this however, between the two books I don't recall Newarre being mentioned by name again.

Answer (score 2):

The inn is in Newarre but, more specifically, there is a good argument [here](https://www.tor.com/blogs/2011/08/rothfuss-reread-speculative-summary-part-1-qinside-edges-holesq-speculations-on-imaginary-geography) placing Newarre in north-west Vintas.